# Does every Archimedian partially ordered division ring embed in the reals?

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields, division-ring

I know that any Archimedian totally ordered field embeds into the real numbers.
Does this result extend to a priori partially ordered field?

A division ring is basically a noncommutative field.
Does an Archimedian totally ordered division ring embed into the real numbers?
What about partially ordered ones?

I do know of examples of totally ordered division rings that do not embed into the real numbers but they are all non-Archimedian.

Comment: Archimedean appears to imply totally ordered by definition. Did you have alternative definitions than the ones on Wikipedia in mind?

Comment: So with Archimedity I mean $a\leq b+\frac1n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a\leq b$. It is not clear to me why this would imply being totally ordered

Comment: That definition doesn't require being totally ordered, but it is different from the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_group), which was the one that I was thinking of.

Comment: Ah yes that is indeed a different definition. But I still don't see how that property would make the field totally ordered.
(the definition I had is that of an Archimedian unit in an order unit space)